# how to monitor the death of child actor that gets spawned

Tags: java, testing, akka, parent-child

I have the following parent - child relationship

```
public class ParentActor extends UntypedActor {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {

        if (msg instanceof Command) {
            final String data = ((Command) msg).getData();
            final Event event = new Event(data, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
ActorRef childActor = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(ChildActor.class), "child-actor");

            childActor.tell(event, getSelf());
        } else if (msg.equals("echo")) {
            log.info("ECHO!");
        }
    }
}
public class ChildActor extends UntypedActor {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object msg) {
        log.info("Received Event: " + msg);
        //PoisonPill and kill self
    }


}
```

How do I write a test that watches and verfies that the child actor dies after sending message to parent?

I have the following that results into an assertion timeout

```
@Before
     childProps = Props.create(ForwarderActor.class, childProbe.getRef());
     childRef = TestActorRef.create(system, childProps);



  @Test
public void myTest () {
    underTest.tell("send parent message);
    childProbe.expectMsgClass(Terminated.class);
}
```

And the forwarder actor

```
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;


public class ForwarderActor extends UntypedActor {
    final ActorRef target;
    public ForwarderActor(ActorRef target) {
        this.target = target;
    }
    public void onReceive(Object msg) {
        target.forward(msg, getContext());
    }
}
```

I guess the problem here is that my child actor is not passed in via Props but is rather initialised in the parent actor itself, is this bad design? How can I test this set up?

Comment: Have you seen the documentation on this topic: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/testing.html#Testing_parent-child_relationships

Comment: yes I have, I have updated the question